# android kotlin room failing to get response from query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

here's the part where i get the problem

```
        if(workout == null) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                newWorkoutAndStepsId = workoutDao.insert(Workout("")).toInt()
                Log.e(tag, "steps new : ${newWorkoutAndStepsId}")
                stepDao.insert(Step("Warm Up Jumping Jacks", 1, false, "minute", newWorkoutAndStepsId))
                stepDao.insert(Step("Rest", 15, true, "second", newWorkoutAndStepsId))

                var newWorkoutAndSteps = workoutDao.getById(newWorkoutAndStepsId).first().first()
                workout = newWorkoutAndSteps.workout
                var workoutId = newWorkoutAndSteps.workout.workoutId
                steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(workoutId)
                //steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(25)
                Log.e(tag, "steps new : ${newWorkoutAndSteps.workout.workoutId}")
            }

        }else{
            viewModelScope.launch {
                workoutWithSteps = workoutDao.getById(workout!!.workoutId)
                var workoutId = workoutWithSteps.first().first().workout.workoutId
                steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(workoutId)
                //steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(25)
                Log.e(tag, "steps old : ${workoutWithSteps.first().first().workout.workoutId}")
            }
        }
    }
```

i am checking if a workout was passed to the fragment and either making a new one and making two workout steps for it, then getting those steps so i can get them from the fragment later, or getting an existing workout and steps,

so here's the problem
`steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(workoutId)`
doesn't work, i get no steps returned, but when i change it to for example `steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(25)` it works fine,

here's the dao function

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM step_table WHERE workoutParentId=:workoutId")
    fun getWorkoutSteps(workoutId: Int): Flow<List<Step>>
```

thank you

Comment: Can you show the output of this line: Log.e(tag, "steps new : ${newWorkoutAndSteps.workout.workoutId}")

Comment: @gioravered E/ADD_EDIT_VIEWMODEL: steps new : 30

Comment: And does 30 work when trying hard coded? Can you show the code for insert method?

Comment: yes hard coded does work,     @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(step: Step) , and new steps do get created

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't query the database for an ID you already have.
If the workout instance is not null you already have the `workoutId` to pass to the `getWorkoutSteps` function.
Otherwise, if the workout is null, once the insert function returns the newly create ID, you can use it in the query.

Try to simplify your code like this and see if it works:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    workout?.let { workout -> 
        // Workout is not null
        steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(workout.workoutId)
        Log.e(tag, "steps old : ${workout.workoutId}")
    } ?: run {
        // Workout is null, let's create it
        val newWorkoutAndStepsId = workoutDao.insert(Workout("")).toInt()
        Log.e(tag, "steps new : ${newWorkoutAndStepsId}")
        stepDao.insert(Step("Warm Up Jumping Jacks", 1, false, "minute", newWorkoutAndStepsId))
        stepDao.insert(Step("Rest", 15, true, "second", newWorkoutAndStepsId))

        steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(newWorkoutAndStepsId)
        //steps = stepDao.getWorkoutSteps(25)
        Log.e(tag, "steps new : ${newWorkoutAndSteps.workout.workoutId}")
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, this works, but in the case of the new inserted steps they still don't get returned